# External editor support in vimfx+firefox

Tags: firefox, vim

In `vimperator`, I can use `Ctrl+I` to edit text input in vim. Is there any equivalent in `vimfx` plugin for firefox? I  like the  simpler interface vimfx provides but without external editor support, I find it lacking a very important feature I use daily from vimperator.

Answer (score 4):

VimFX itself does not have this feature but you can always install [It's
All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) that does exactly that.

After the installation you only need to configure the editor (gvim) and
the shortcut. I found <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> too overloaded, so I
opted for <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.